# Django admin do not display all fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-modeladmin

This question is created to help other people with similar problem. I know how to fix the issue, but I'm also interested Why this happens.

In my models.py I've had a model

```
class CEOSetting(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Заголовок', help_text='Содержимое тега <title>. Так-же поддерживает переменные.', max_length=200, blank=True)
    page = models.CharField('Описание страницы', max_length=120)
    key = models.CharField('Ключ', max_length=50, unique=True)
    variables = models.TextField('Доступные переменные', null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField('Meta description', blank=True)
    keywords = models.TextField('Meta keywords', blank=True)
    robots = models.TextField('Meta robots', blank=True)
```

And registered this model in `admin.py`

```
@admin.register(CEOSetting)
class CEOSettingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

When I've tried to add or edit `CEOSetting` record in admin, the admin site was showing me only one field (`title`) and nothing more. Even buttons at bottom of the page were missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried lots of different methods to figure out what's the problem and finally understood that `<title>` in help_text attribute of `title` field was causing the issue.

When `help_text` is rendered, Django treats `<title>` as opened tag, which remains opened until the end of page.

I don't know why it works in a such way. As I remember, value in `help_text` do not render as safe html automatically, but it seems to me that this `<title>` is treated as opened tag and blocks rendering for any subsequent html.

Answer (score -1):

from django.contrib import admin

import YourApp.models as model

admin.site.register(model.CEOSetting)

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question